# How to set the height of tableview dynamically based on content but it should maintain a minimum distance from bottom button?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I have UITableview as shown in the image and this is at a distance of 20 points from the bottom button. So it has no height constraint as of now, it is just pinned to with the top view at 0 margin and 20 from the bottom button.

Now what I want is to adjust the frame of this tableview if there are only 2-3 cells or to 0 height if there are no cells.

I am not really sure about the order in which the `updateLayoutconstraints` and other related methods have to be called.All I am pretty sure about is that I will have to have a height constraint on the tableview which will be connected via code to the xib and I will have to update it once the `reloadData` on tableView is called.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already thinking in the right direction.

Here are the steps to make it work:

1. Change the button top constraint relation to `greaterThanOrEqual`
2. Add a tableView height constraint as `@IBOutlet` to your ViewController. Change this constraint's priority from `Required` to `High` to avoid an Auto Layout error when the contentSize is greater than the available height
3. Override `updateViewConstraints()` in your UIViewController and set the height constraint's constant to `tableView.contentSize.height`
4. Call `updateViewConstraints()` whenever the number of rows changes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is buttom constraint of your UIButton which is "equal" you can change it to "greater than" when table view height decrease button will change position in y and will come uper place